# Draft JS - mention- plugins produce this: Warning: React does not recognize the isFocused prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm facing a problem when it comes to involving the draft-js-mention-plugin, into my app. Please, have a look:

> "Warning: React does not recognize the isFocused prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase isfocused instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

Please, find the print screen according to this problem:

[image]

Btw, this issue can be found in this example, too: https://codesandbox.io/s/x2r59zo4j4

Has anyone had the same warning?! Or anyone did a mention in reactjs using draftjs, or even in vanilla javascript? I just need to rely on an example to get things done (i'm a newbie on JS, React JS) ...thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is because in your component your declare

```
const { blabla, foo, bar} = this.props
```

And in your render :

```
<Component 
    blabla={blabla}
    foo={foo}
    bar={bar}
    {...this.props} />
```

React interprets you pass twice your props and give you a warning in the console